# Is it possible to make a variable that can be an array or a non-array?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to be able to do something like

```
public string[]|string stringsOrSingleString;
```

I want to create a variable that can be an array or a non-array of a specific type (a string in the example).

Example usage

I want to be able to do `stringsOrSingleString = "bla"` or `stringsOrSingleString = new string[] { "bla" };`

Do I need a custom class to do this? Preferably, I don't want to use a custom class, but if necessary then ok.

I should be able to tell later on if the value assigned was an array or non-array, using typeof or is, or something.

The whole reason for this ordeal is that I have a javascript API(that I didn't create), and I am trying to make a C# api that follows the JS api/syntax as close as possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean in a `class SomeClass<T>` where you have a Field defined as `public T? stringsOrSingleString;`? Does it need explicit constraints? Is it meant to be used in a converter of some sort? Container for deserialization purposes?

Comment: `string[]` is already capable representing this. It can either store one string (when `Length == 1`) or strings (when `Length != 1`)

Comment: Yes I know a string array can store just one string, but I don't want to use the array syntax when it's just one value

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's more clear

Comment: So how do you expect to use this thing?  You've shown how you expect to assign a value to it, but how do you plan to do anything with it since you don't know if it's a single value or multiple values?

Comment: I should be able to check if the value assigned is an array or not using typeof or is, I hope.

Comment: I edited the question once again to add more context.

Comment: @savram That ***so*** much more inconvenient than sometimes needing to create an array when assigning a single object.  That's a *ton* more code, that's way more complicated, way more error prone, and substantially less performant.  Why in the world would you rather do that?

Comment: It's like I said, there's a javascript api that I am trying to replicate on the C# side. There's this variable that accepts a string or a string array, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: C# isn't javascript.  Trying to design your C# programs as if they're javascript programs is just going to result in lots of problems for you and the consumers of your API..  That said, this is extremely poor practice in javascript for exactly the same reason it's extremely hard to work with in C#.  Needing to check the type of a variable and do different things depending on what it actually is is extremely inconvenient and error prone.

Comment: I'm actually being successful in making the api very similar. And this is a good thing because most users will be coming from the JS world, so it will be easier for them. For this array/non-array issue, I chose to simply make the variable an array and that's it. It seems like there isn't an easy solution to this problem with C#. I thought there was something that could be done with generics, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want something like this?

```
public class Item<T>
{
    public T Value => this.Values.Length > 0 ? this.Values[0] : default(T);

    public T[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

The class has an array of values and a single value. There are some implementations like this, for example, when you select files with `OpenFileDialog`: you have a list of files (for `MultiSelect` case) and also a single `SelectedFile`. My answer is focused with this in mind. If you need another thing, give more information.

**UPDATE**

You can update previous class in this way:

```
public class Item<T>
{
    public T Value => this.Values.Length > 0 ? this.Values[0] : default(T);

    public T[] Values { get; set; }

    public T this[int index] => this.Values[index];

    public static implicit operator Item<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Item<T> { Values = new[] { value } };
    }

    public static implicit operator Item<T>(List<T> values)
    {
        return new Item<T> { Values = values.ToArray() };
    }

    public static implicit operator Item<T>(T[] values)
    {
        return new Item<T> { Values = values };
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Item<string> item = "Item1";
string text = item.Value;
string sameText = item[0];

Item<string> items = new[] { "Item1", "Item2" };
string[] texts = item.Values;
string item1 = item[0];
string item2 = item[1];
```

You can create an instance using a simple object or an array. You can access to the first value using `Value` property and to all items using `Values`. Or use the indexer property to access to any item.

In C# you need to know the type of the variable. It's difficult work in the same form of JavaScript. They are very different languages.

Comment: Can you show me how can I use this class? Can you explain to me this line 
public T Value => this.Values.Length > 0 ? this.Values[0] : default(T);
I never saw something like this. I know arrow functions, but this is supposed to be a field, what's an arrow function doing here?

Comment: Preferably I don't want to create a class for this, but if it's necessary then ok

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's more clear.

Comment: You set Values property with an array but you can work with this array or get the first item using Value property, that return the first array item or the default value when the array is empty.

Comment: I see, no, this is not what I want. I edited the question with a practical example.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This is the best solution for C#.